# STM32 Bare Metal C - Can't get LED to work

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller, microprocessors

So I'm currently following a course for the STM32 Microprocessor however, I seem to fail at even the most basic thing: turning a LED on. The complete code is at the bottom of this post.

Important:

- The hardware is functioning properly.
- I am using a STM32L432KC.

First of all, we have to figure out on what pin the built-in LED is. According to the manufacturers manual, the LED should be on pin D13 (PB3).
[image]

---

Okay so we're looking for PB3. According to the datasheet of the STM32L432KC, PB3 is on the B port and therefore connected to the high performance bus as suggested in the image below.
[image]

---

Cool. So our bus is AHB2 and we're working with GPIOB. Now we have to enable the clock on that bus using the RCC_AHB3ENR register. Now, this is the part where I'm probably going to make mistakes (as this post otherwise wouldn't exist), so please pay close attention. If I understand correctly, I want bit 1 to be set to 1 as this indicates that 'GPIOBEN' is set to 'IO port B clock enabled.'.
[image]
[image]

This leads me to believe that I should set the bus register as follows:

```c
RCC->AHB2ENR |= 0x2;
```

---

Next up I have to set the mode of the GPIO pin to output. According to the course and my documentation, this is done using GPIOx_MODER.
[image]

This leads me to believe that I should set the GPIO mode as follows:

```c
GPIOB->MODER |= 0x40;
```

---

And last but not least to turn the actual LED on we have to set the output data register which is GPIOx_ODR.
[image]

This leads me to believe that I should set the data as follows:

```c
GPIOB->ODR = 0x8;
```

---

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but this is the first time I'm working with registers on such a deep level. I must be overlooking something but I've tried multiple examples and had no success. All help is appreciated.
This is the complete code:

```c
// PB3 - User LED
// RCC->AHB2ENR
// GPIOx_MODER
// GPIOx_ODR

#include "stm32l4xx.h"

int main(void)
{
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= 0x2;
    GPIOB->MODER |= 0x40;

    while(1)
    {
        GPIOB->ODR = 0x8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mode register is not configured correctly.  Your line of code

```
GPIOB->MODER |= 0x40;
```

can only set bits, it cannot clear them.  And you have too many bits set, as the reset value of each pair is `11` and the entire register is `FFFF FFFF` for ports C-E, `FFFF FEBF` for port B.

You should use

```
GPIOB->MODER = (GPIOB->MODER & 0xFFFFFF3F) | 0x00000040;
```

<strike>although because the reset state is guaranteed, this will also work:</strike>

```
GPIOB->MODER &= 0xFFFFFF7F; // equivalently, ~0x0080
```

The note in the documentation of `11 analog mode (reset state)` is not accurate for all pins.  Several are in `10 alternate function` mode at reset, including PB3.  So you need to both clear one bit and set one.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as this resolved my issue however, two things are not clear to me. 

First of all:
- I don't understand how the entire register is FFFF FFFF as it states that the reset values for port B are FFFF FEBF.
- Your &= shorthand does not appear to work. Your first answer does.


I guess I'll have to read up on some more bitwise operators.

Comment: "GPIOB->MODER &= 0xFFFFFF7F;" shouldn't be a compound AND. If you remove the ampersand it works.

Comment: @Arjan: It is correct as `&=`, assuming you don't want to reconfigure any other pins.  Well, it would have been, if the documentation weren't lying.  Answer updated.

Comment: Since this is the initialization code, simply do `GPIOB->MODER = 0x00000040u;`. There's no point in reading an uninitialized register before writing to it for the first time.

Comment: @Lundin: That rapidly fails as project complexity grows, unless you plan to initialize all port B pins in a single place.  A lot of projects like to organize the initialization code according to logical hierarchy (measuring X vs controlling Y) rather than hardware hierarchy (port A vs port B).  I generally do use the "all port A setup together" style, because you need to organize part of the design according to hardware in order to get a working PCB without crosstalk between fast digital and sensitive analog signals, but I seem to be in the minority there.

Comment: @Lundin: Then also, it can be problematic to configure floating pins as inputs, at least with FET input stages.

Comment: @Lundin: Finally, I believe that your recommendation would disable the debug port

Comment: On professional projects you must set all ports at one place, as soon out of reset as possible. Because unfortunately most MCUs come with these default configured for low current consumption, but more often you want to set unused data direction registers as outputs for immunity/EMI reasons. So data direction and pull resistor registers should be set asap, from the reset vector or as part of the CRT. These electrical arguments supersedes all program design arguments.

Comment: @Lundin: A hardware design where the reset values of ports cause damage is a defective design.  You may save a tiny bit of battery power by doing the configuration earlier.  Noise immunity doesn't matter during startup, with the possible exception of calibration of analog peripherals (but these have to wait for far more than just pin setups to stabilize).  The fact is that a production design shouldn't leave pins floating that don't have pull resistors enabled as power-on-reset defaults.  Dev kits generally do, only because they don't know what pins the dev design will actually use.

Comment: MCU manufacturers always leave all pins as inputs by default, so that they can brag about low current consumption. This means that they are unprotected save for internal diodes - but a transient frying those diodes will leave the port broken no matter. Sadly, many designs leave pins floating, also.